# Active Directory - Remove custom attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I created a custom attribute in the AD schema like this:

```
$adSchema = (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext

$attributeName = 'TestAttribute'
$OID = "1.2.840.113556.1.8000.2554.2000.1.1"

$attributeAttributes = @{
  lDAPDisplayName = $attributeName;
  attributeId = $OID;
  oMSyntax = 64; # type of attribute = String (Unicode), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/7cda533e-d7a4-4aec-a517-91d02ff4a1aa
  attributeSyntax = '2.5.5.12'; # type of attribute = String (Unicode), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/7cda533e-d7a4-4aec-a517-91d02ff4a1aa
  searchflags = 0; # set the to "1" if you want AD to index this attribute
}
New-ADObject -Name $attributeName -Type attributeSchema -Path $adSchema -OtherAttributes $attributeAttributes
```

For some reason, I am unable to remove this attribute. Apart from creating the attribute, I did not use the attribute at all. (I.e. attaching it to a `classSchema`)

What I'm trying to do (as enterprise admin/schema admin) is this:

```
Get-ADObject -SearchBase $adSchema -Filter 'name -eq "TestAttribute"' | Remove-ADObject -Confirm:$false
```

At first, this resulted in:

```
Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (CN=TestAttribute,...rg-intern,DC=de:ADObject) [Remove-ADObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADObject
```

This was most likely caused by the inherited ACLs not containing Delete permission for the Enterprise Admin Group. I have since added such an ACL directly on the object, and now the following error occurs:

```
Remove-ADObject : The requested delete operation could not be performed
At line:1 char:71
+ ... ma -Filter 'name -eq "TestAttribute"' | Remove-ADObject -Confirm:$false
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=TestAttribute,...rg-intern,DC=de:ADObject) [Remove-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8398,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADObject
```

I'd be glad about any hints on how I can remove this attribute from the schema. (It was not used in any objects)

Comment: Type $PROFILE to see you location for your profile.  Open file and see if it was added to your profile.

Comment: Read following.  It is a clue.  I think is has to do with the ps1xml file. https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove attributes from AD schema?](https://serverfault.com/q/601989/536173)

Answer (score 2):

Know that Microsoft does not support removing attribute from schema, even if you added them. This is usually a one-shot irreversible operation.

If really needed you can deactivate those attributes or classes.

MS even allows redefining them once deactivated.

The challenges root from Active Directory being multi-master replication system so imagine one scenario where a domain controller on a remote site might have attributes with values for which the schema definition is altogether removed from head office, it will render remote DC with inconsistent state.

So your one option then is authoritative restore to old state of Active Directory at the point when that schema change was not done, that would be a supported path, although expensive operation if your setup is big with number of DCs

You last option is to force remove such schema classes and attributes, that is unsupported and risky through modification of ACL. But you can still do that: https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/your-mission-delete-ad-schema

Comment: Unfortunately, even after setting the "Schema Update Allow" registry value and adding the "Delete All Child Objects" ACL for the Schema Admins Group on the Schema Container, deleting the attribute still does not work. Error: `Operation failed. Error Code: 0x20ce. The requested delete operation could not be performed.`

Comment: Ensure that 1) you are in schema admins group & Ent admins group 2) you are on forest root DC(s) 3) The object is not protected from accidental deletion option 4) ACL is set to allow 5) no deny permission to block your operation.